# Net 6 DLL - Where is all its dependencies?

Tags: vb.net, .net-core, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I'm getting crazy here.

I created a Net-Core 6.0 DLL and set the PUBLISH settings as:

- Release
- Net6.0
- Self-Contained
- win-x64
- Enable ReadyToRun compilation

The library has 4 Nuget packages and a set of custom libraries present on my disk.

**When I publish, I see only the DLL within the RELEASE folder and a ".nupkg" within the "win-x64" folder.** Where are all the required DLLs of my project, including the Nuget Packages and dependencies?

When I created another console app some days before, I could see all of them in PUBLISH folder.

I appreciate any help on this.

**EDIT**

I created another project (a Windows Forms App) to link this DLL. Both contain the same NuGet packages and libraries. When I publish the solution, I see the expected results. But again, if I publish ONLY the DLL project, I see only the above explained.